# No suitable constructor found for ClassUser(no arguments)

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to get my head around inheritance.

The error is `no suitable constructor found for ClassUser(no arguments)` appears at `public ClassAdmin(String data)` and I haven't found any solutions of help to me.

This is my a snippet of my `ClassUser`:

```
public class ClassUser {

public String id;
public String password;
public String name;
public String address;
public String contact;
public String role;


public ClassUser(String id, String password, String name, String address, String contact, String role){

    this.id = id;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.role = role;
}

public ClassUser(String data){
    String[] dataArray = data.split(",");
    this.id = dataArray[0];
    this.password = dataArray[1];
    this.name = dataArray[2];
    this.address = dataArray[3];
    this.contact = dataArray[4];
    this.role = dataArray[5];
}
```

This is a snippet of my `ClassAdmin`:

```
public class ClassAdmin extends ClassUser{

    public String email;

public ClassAdmin(String id, String password, String name, String contact, 
String email)
{
    super(id+password+name+contact);
    this.email = email;
}
public ClassAdmin(String data){ //problem
    String[] dataArray = data.split(",");
    this.id = dataArray[0];
    this.password = dataArray[1];
    this.name = dataArray[2];
    this.contact = dataArray[3];
    this.email = dataArray[4];
}
```

Comment: Please call super constructor first in "public ClassAdmin(String data){"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add invokes of the parent constructor `super(data);` to the `public ClassAdmin(String data)` constructor as well.

Because if you don't call parent constructor, you can't create child object. First of all, parent object need to be created. And only after that instantiation of the child object can be executed.

The main reason of the error is that, if you're not providing, explicitly, invocation of the super class constructor, Java compiler tries to find default super class constructor with no argument and in your case there is no default no argument constructor in the `ClassUser` class.

You can fix in a two ways:

- by adding default constructor to the `ClassUser`:

  ```
  public ClassUser() {
      //some additional logic 
  }
  ```
- by adding call of the super class constructor:

  ```
  public ClassAdmin(String data) {
      super(data);
      String[] dataArray = data.split(",");
      this.id = dataArray[0];
      this.password = dataArray[1];
      this.name = dataArray[2];
      this.contact = dataArray[3];
      this.email = dataArray[4];
  }
  ```

It depends on your implementation, but be aware that after you will have called super class constructor, you will have overridden some of the properties in your `ClassAdmin` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call supper constructor into :

```
public class ClassAdmin extends ClassUser {

    public String email;

    public ClassAdmin(String id, String password, String name, String contact,
                      String email) {
        super(id + password + name + contact);
        this.email = email;
    }

    public ClassAdmin(String data) { //problem
        super(data);
        String[] dataArray = data.split(",");

        this.id = dataArray[0];
        this.password = dataArray[1];
        this.name = dataArray[2];
        this.contact = dataArray[3];
        this.email = dataArray[4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `super()` explicitly in the second `ClassAdmin` constructor so the compiler add `super()` call without any parameters. You don't have parameterless `ClassUser` constructor so you are getting the error.

Add explicit `super` call

```
public ClassAdmin(String data) {
    super(data.split(",")[0] + data.split(",")[1] + data.split(",")[2] + data.split(",")[3]);
    //...
}
```

Or use private `ClassAdmin` constructor to avoid repeating use of `data.split(",")` (still two uses though)

```
public ClassAdmin(String data) {
  this(data.split(","));
  //...
}

private ClassAdmin(String[] dataArray) {
    super(dataArray[0] + dataArray[1] + dataArray[2] + dataArray[3]);
}
```

Or create parameterless `ClassUser` constructor

```
public ClassUser() { }
```

Comment: @Eran sure, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `default constructor` present in `ClassUser` but parameterised constructor present, so while extending the `ClassUser` you should call

```
ClassUser(data)
```

or

```
ClassUser(String id, String password, String name, String address, String contact, String role)
```

using `super` [super- java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

```
super(data)
```

or

```
super(id, password, name, address, contact, role)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works. When you create an instance of Child Class, you need to instantiate member variables of parent/super class as well. If you have a default constructor in Super class then those member variables gets initialized to their default values. If you don't have a default constructor you will have to make a call to parameterized constructor to initialize them. That is why you require a call to **super(date)** in your *ClassAdmin* constructor.

Also you don't have to initialize super class member variables like id,password,name etc. in *ClassAdmnin* constructor. Once you add a super(data) call in this constructor, the member variables of parent class will get initialized in parent class constructor itself.

Moreover your current code will throw NullPointerException as you are getting value from an array based on index without checking the size of array. If you see first constructor of *ClassAdmin* there is no comma (,) in the string which you are sending to Super class constructor. You can append it like *super(id+ "," +password+ "," +name + ","+contact)*

```html
public ClassAdmin(String data){
    super(data);   // Add this line and it should fix the problem.
    String[] dataArray = data.split(",");
    this.id = dataArray[0];
    this.password = dataArray[1];
    this.name = dataArray[2];
    this.contact = dataArray[3];
    this.email = dataArray[4];
}
```